# Can anyone shed some light on error I'm receiving when executing .net Console application. (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040111)

Tags: c#, .net, com, console-application, moveit

I have a .net (framework version 4.5.1) console application that encounters the following error when it is executed:

```
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040111): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F374E943-076A-40B9-813E- 0FBFB823E638} failed due to the following error: 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE)).
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
```

I have tried changing the Platform target to X86 based on other posts I've found similar to this but that has not worked for me. The .dll that is being referenced in my console application is Interop.MOVEitAPI.dll. Could the problem be from a mismatch in the version of the MOVEitAPI that is referenced in the console application and the version that is actually installed on the server the console app is running on ?

Comment: Without seeing the code that is causing this error, we can only speculate, I feel.

Comment: It means the class is known to COM (it is registered somehow to the system) but the COM server (the real dll for which Interop.MOVEitAPI is only a metadata wrapper) cannot provide it when asked for. It's a quite unusual error. It could happen for example if you register the COM server in a given version and then replace the DLL in-place w/o registering it again. Or if an update/setup succeeded in registering to COM but not in copying binaries (or the reverse)

Answer (score 0):

On the machine that you are executing the program, make sure you have the original COM MOVEitAPI.dll that was used to build the program and make sure that DLL is registered.
To register a DLL, run

```
regsvr32 MOVEitAPI.dll
```

as admin in command prompt.